# Prevent Search Spiders from accessing a Rails 3 nested resource with robots.txt

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, robots.txt

I'm trying to prevent Google, Yahoo et al from hitting my /products/ID/purchase page and am unsure on how to do it.

I currently block them from hitting sign in with the following:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /sign_in
```

Can I do something like the following?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /products/*/purchase
```

Or should it be:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /purchase
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to block `/products/ID/purchase` but allow `/products/ID`.

Your last suggestion would only block pages that **start with** "purchase":

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /purchase
```

So this is not what you want.

You'd need your second suggestion:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /products/*/purchase
```

This would block all URLs that start with `/products/`, followed by any character(s), followed by `/purchase`.

Note: It uses the wildcard `*`. In the original robots.txt "specification", this is not a character with special meaning. However, some search engines extended the spec and use it as a kind of wildcard. So it [should work for Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt) and probably some other search engines, but you can't bet that it would work with all the other crawlers/bots.

So your robots.txt could look like:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /sign_in
Disallow: /products/*/purchase
```

Also note that some search engines (including Google) might still list a URL in their search results (without title/snippet) although it is blocked in robots.txt. This might be the case when they find a link to a blocked page on a page that is allowed to be crawled. To prevent this, you'd have to `noindex` the document.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt) `Disallow: /products/*/purchase` should work.
But [according to robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) this doesn't work.